# I need a mathematical symbolic calculator

Tags: windows, symbolic-algebra

I need to do bitwise boolean operators on complex numbers, to find the properties of certain boolean operators, combined with addition and multiplication.

I tried matlab, but is totally useless, because it doesn't do bitwise operators on real numbers.

It is better if it outputs latex and has flexible plotting capabilities, but is not required.

The stuff I want to do is like

```
f(x,y)=(x-x&y, y-x&y, x&y)   // "&" means bitwise boolean AND
```

and then expand expressions like f(x,y)*f(j,k)
(It should produce 9 terms, to be simplified if possible)

It can use a GUI, or a python library, or R, or another language

I suspect that this is related to geometric algebra, so clifford algebra support would be a plus.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's possible Qalculate (open source) will be able to help you: https://github.com/Qalculate

Comment: Bitwise on IEEE-754, ok... But complex numbers? Are they even standardized? I also wonder where this should go. It the bitwise AND of a 32 bit real number worth any more worth compared to bitwise and of a 32 bit integer?

Comment: Are you thinking of x∈ℂ, y∈ℂ or is it rather x∈ℝ, y∈ℝ and x+yi is the complex number?

Comment: @Thomas Weller I'm thinking C=R² ( C=(x,y)  x∈R, y∈R )